# phone turned off and not turning back on

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, huawei

My phone Huawei P8 Lite was working totally fine but suddenly turned off and now it's not turning back on. the phone was not out of charge when it died and now, as I plug in the charger, after a while it gets warmer meaning (i think) battery is still charged but its neither turning on nor showing any screen.

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: Try connecting to a PC. Do you see your PC make the sound for the USB connection? Also check if a new device appears in the device manager.

Comment: checked, nothing happened.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware failure. You should take it to a repair center as I think the motherboard is short-circuited (the power IC I guess)...

Answer (score 0):

If it's a software problem, you can try holding the power button and volume down button down at the same time and keep holding for at least 10 seconds.

The phone should now boot up and give you a list of options. Use the volume up/down arrows to navigate and power button to select. Find the 'Reboot' option and select it to reboot your phone.

If that doesn't work, could be a hardware problem, which would mean you will need to take it in for repair